# binding, to the viewmodel, of a control located in the template of an ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

Yay,

Perhaps it's a simple question, but i'm stuck on this problem so I need your help.

I got a TextBox, in a DataTemplate, in a ItemsControl.ItemTemplate, in a ItemsControl, and I'd like to get send the typed value in one of my ViewModel's property.

```
ItemsControl 
|ItemsControl.ItemTemplate 
||Datatemplate 
|||Grid 
||||textBox --> Value == > MyViewModel
```

Currently, I have a List of "DisplayedItems", bound to the ItemsControl's "ItemsSource" property that populate the ItemsControl, and the value that I get is received by one of the DisplayedItem in the list, and unfortunately stays there ... And I absolutely don't know how to get it or use it from the ViewModel Class.

```
||||textBox --> Value --> DisplayedItem --?-->ViewModelClass

<ItemsControl Name="IcChoice" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="350" Height="150" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Visibility="{Binding Visible, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>

                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Grid.Row="0"/>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" Visibility="{Binding ComboBoxVisibility}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding HelloWorldViewModel.ReceivedText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Visibility="{Binding TextBoxVisibility}" Grid.Row="1">

                    </TextBox>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Can I get some help ?

Comment: You mean all the items are to bind to one property in the window's viewmodel? That'd be a relativesource binding but it seems a bit of a strange thing. Or do you mean you want the value of a particular item in the collection. In whuch case maybe make your itenscontrol a listbox and bind selecteditem.

Comment: well, if ItemsSource="{Binding Items is your viewmodel collection of DisplayedItem then change to <TextBox Text="{Binding ReceivedText and you will get the data directly in the DisplayedItem

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

I needed to define a particular Data context for my encapsulated controls :

```
  <TextBox   
                        Text="{Binding DataContext.ReceivedText, 
                        ElementName=Hello,  
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                        Mode=TwoWay}" 
                        Visibility="{Binding TextBoxVisibility}" 
                        Grid.Row="1"/>
```

If "Hello" is the Name of my view (it makes the link with the viewModel )